# Populate Listbox with images from directory

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm kinda new at both programming, and WPF.  I know that this is pretty easy, but I nothing I've tried as worked so far.....
I want to fill a Listbox with images from a folder. I also need to know how to force my listbox from allowing scrolling to the side. So far I haven't stumbled upon anything that seems to work.

Here is my C# code that adds the files in chosen folder to a List  Basically I want the Listbox to be use to keep a history log of the pictures that the user has chosen as backgrounds.

```
IList<Bitmap> HistoryImages = new List<Bitmap>();

foreach(String imagefile in Directory.GetFiles( @"C:\ProgramData\etc" ))
{
    HistoryImages.Add( new Bitmap( imagefile) );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found something that worked for me!
**XAML Code:**

```
<ListBox Name="ImageLog" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="True"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Image}" BorderThickness="0" 
    SelectionChanged="ImageLog_SelectionChanged_1">
</ListBox>
```

**C# Code:**

```
foreach(string myFile in Directory.GetFiles( @"C:\ProgramData\MyApp" ) )
{
System.Windows.Controls.Image myLocalImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image(); ;
myLocalImage.Height = 200;
myLocalImage.Margin = new Thickness( 5 );


BitmapImage myImageSource = new BitmapImage();
myImageSource.BeginInit();
myImageSource.UriSource = new Uri( @"file:///" + myFile );
myImageSource.EndInit();
myLocalImage.Source = myImageSource;

filePath.Add( myFile );
ImageLog.Items.Add(myLocalImage);
}
```

Comment: filePath.Add came from where?

Comment: It was a List of strings that was populated with the file path of each file in my target folder 

'public List<String> filePath = new List<string>();'

Answer (score 1):

This requires the basics of [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx). (If you read and understood all that you should be able to do it.)

About the scrolling, set [`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) as [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) on the `ListBox` to `Disabled`

Comment: I understand what Data Binding and data templating are supposed to do, but I can't seem to get it to actually work for me. What am I trying to data bind the listbox too?  A folder of images? A list contained in the C# code?  Another random object?

Comment: @Usta put the Xaml of your list box into your question and show what you have tried.  H.B.'s answer is fine given the paucity of information in your question.

Comment: @GarryVass  
My code was something like... I had removed much of the code because it wasn't working right before I asked the question =(
'code'
<Listbox ItemsSoruce="{Binding Path="C:\ProgramData\etc}">
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Image Source=("//file:C:\ProgramData\etc" />
</DataTemplate>
</Listbox>
'code'

I've also tried adding a custom clr-namespace but I couldn't figure that out either....

Comment: @Usta, this code betrays a fundamental gap in understanding binding. 'Path' does not refer to your C: drive for example.  The best idea is to push back on your project and take in some theory.

Comment: Thanks for telling me!  I had no idea that I didn't know how to do this!  Where/How would I go about finding out how to use DataBinding? Soon as I finish the listbox, the project will be done.  And I know that it is relatively simple to do, I am just familiar enough with WPF to really guess how it should go....

Comment: @Usta: See those two links in the first sentence of my answer?